# Why a 750w electric drill costs about 30€, and a standalone 750w electric motor costs about 120€?

Tags: dc-motor

Here two examples:

https://www.amazon.es/Einhell-TC-ID-710-Taladro-percutor/dp/B00UFZEGKU/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1505302887&sr=8-2&keywords=taladro+einhell

[https://www.amazon.com/36V48V-Electric-Vehicle-Bracket-Scooter/dp/B01DOW82O6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DOW82O6)

It is evident the standalone motor of this example is much bigger. But... so what If both have equal power?

The standalone motor has more torque and less speed, I guess, but... this is 4 times the price. Which is the feature of the standalone motor that justifies this price difference?

Edit: Now that I am thinking, the drill motor may not be a DC motor, but AC motor.

Comment: Build quality, price point...

Comment: This is an economics question, not an electronics question.

Comment: Quality and price - I can buy entire audio amplifiers on ebay for the price I pay for one high-quality audio potentiometer from reputable brands.

Comment: Buying a million of the motors built into the drill will probably cost 1€ each or so.

Comment: That standalone motor is designed to operation for 20 years continuous operation. The drill motor is good for? 10 hours?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with electronic design and should be closed.

Comment: "750 W drill" is 750 W input power for 1 ms with locked rotor and thus 0 W output. Perhaps 200 W output would be possible for a minute at optimum speed and torque for a minute without overheating. The other one could very well be 750 W output indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drill has a cheap crummy [universal motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_motor) because this type of motor is the cheapest way to cram lots of power and torque into a small space. It is also very light.

It is also designed for intermittent use, overheats quickly, chews through brushes, and has very low efficiency (like 30-40%)...

The other DC brushed motor uses permanent magnets instead of coils for magnetization, so it will have much better **efficiency** (it specifies 78%), it will heat less for the same mechanical power output. It will be heavier, use a lot more copper due to the lower voltage (higher current), have more robust brushes, and be generally a lot more "serious" design.

So it's more expensive.

Answer (score 8):

The drill motor operates with a very low duty cycle, with plenty of time to cool off between operations. An industrial motor is generally designed to operate continuously (100% duty cycle). The latter has a lot more material in it, which is the primary thing that drives up the cost.

Also, the volumes in which the two types are manufactured are very different, which also affects the cost.

Comment: Not only the duty cycle, but also the total operating time is different.

Comment: @Uwe: Yes, that is implied, plus analogsystemsrf already said that in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

750W for 230V AC requires 3.3A
750W for 48V DC requires 15.6A
More current = more copper = more pennies

Comment: Does it really have so much copper the DC motor as to add 90€ ?

Comment: @pfernandez that is not the only reason, of course. Dave Tweed gave you better answer.